# acumatica _RowInserting events are not triggered when click on 'add row' in the grid

Tags: acumatica

I am have problem with Grid in Checks and Payments screen. When I click on "Add row" button a new row appears in the grid, but not in cache. Events such as **`APAdjust_RowInserting`**, **`APAdjust_RowInserted`** are not triggered.

Maybe somebody know why this happens?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier to help you. Without showing any code it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 4):

To trigger a callback to the server as soon as a new row is inserted in a grid, you need to add the tag `<Mode InitNewRow="true" />`.

Here's an example:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="100%" Caption="Temporary Credit Limit History"
    SkinID="Details">
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="ARTempCreditLimitRecord">
            <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CustomerID" TextAlign="Right" Visible="False" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="StartDate" Width="90px" AutoCallBack="True" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EndDate" Width="90px" AutoCallBack="True" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TempCreditLimit" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LineID" TextAlign="Right" Visible="False" />
            </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <Mode InitNewRow="True" />
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
</px:PXGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is worked, new row in the grid placed in the Cache.Inserted and Cache<APAjust>.Current = "our new row", but if i change some values in this row Cache<APAjust>.Current = null , maybe you know why this happends?