# Trying to customize JAMS LaborEntry screen, looking for the line of code that will update the header

Tags: acumatica

Brand new to Acumatica development and stuck on a simple thing. :(

I am customizing the LaborEntry screen of the JAMS MFG.
I have added a field to the header by extending the AMBatch DAC, called UsrTimeClocked.

For now I simply wish to set this field to a number right at the end of the RowInserted event at the detail level of the AMMTran and see my number on the screen, up on the header AMBatch.

```
    public class LaborEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<LaborEntry>
    {
        protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<AMMTran> e)
        {
            AMBatchExt ext = Base.batch.Current.GetExtension<AMBatchExt>();
            ext.UsrTimeClocked = 5.32;
//Insert line to update the correct object to see 5.32 in the TextBox, before RowSelected is done.
        }
    }
```

As is my value goes in the field and any refresh/save/delete of the row does update the correct object and I see my value where I want it. I wish to know the way to force this update.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. I tested your logic and it's working correctly: after the line is inserted, the header value is set. Then I can save the record and the value is persisted in the DB. From your post, it appears that that is also the behavior you are having. What are you looking to clarify exactly?

Comment: The value is assigned to the field, but does NOT show up in the web control as soon as the rowinserted is over. The value does show in the web control (since it is there) only after I perform another action on the webpage, like save or remove the row or refresh... I want to force the web control to "refresh" and show the value before the rowinserted event is over.

Comment: is the value assigned after you enter the first value from the grid? For instance, the ProductionNbr?

Comment: Yup, it is. Anything that updates that screen, which is the command I am looking for to stick in the rowinserted and have it done before the event ends... if possible...

Comment: This article may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114503/acumatica-rowinserting-events-are-not-triggered-when-click-on-add-row-in-the

Comment: That might work for the rowselected, haven't tried to be honest, because what I am looking for is the code line that will do that. Something like: Base.batch.UpdateCurrent(); (which should have worked IF I understand things correctly)...

Comment: I used to try adjusting field values like that early on, but I found in my case other ways work better.  You might consider leveraging PXDefault for constant values or PXFormula for mathmatical values in the DAC Extension if possible.  Alternatively, I have a fondness for leveraging the FieldDefaulting event coupled with SetDefaultExt when I need to do more complex business logic in setting the value.  (Define the business logic in FieldDefaulting and call SetDefaultExt from the FieldUpdated event for each field that affects UsrTimeClocked).